# How do you call the type of college work you do for the whole year (2 semesters)?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Russian colleges / universities we have a type of work similar to thesis, which you do for 2 semesters, and in the end you defend it like thesis, except it's not thesis, not even bachelor's thesis. Is there a name for it in English?

Example of usage:

For my second year's THIS_WORD I researched and analyzed HPC topologies.

Comment: You might be talking about an [independent study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_study)?

Comment: @KevinWorkman from the description on wikipedia it looks like the answer. However I've never encountered this combination of words with this meaning before.

Comment: I'm not sure the United States has exactly what you're talking about, so you might not find an exact match in English. Maybe there's a word in British English. But in American English, I think you're going to either have to describe the work (since there isn't an exact match) or settle for something that's "close enough" like an independent study.

Comment: A fairly generic term would be **research project**.  There is no implication of its duration. You could say "For my second-year research project, I studied HPC topologies."

Comment: Regardless of what phrase you settle on to call it, please understand that this is much less common, and certainly not routine, in US colleges.

Comment: I don't know that I'd need any word at all besides _year._ Your example would then be "For my second year, I researched and analyzed HPC topologies."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a single word and the final grade doesn’t depend on defending a thesis, but [“Full-year (also called yearlong) courses”](https://www.reed.edu/academic/gbook/acad_pol/full_year_course.html)  generally span 2 semesters (or 3 trimesters) and, at Reed College, “are graded cumulatively [with] the final grade appear[ing] on the transcript for both semesters of the course.”

The University of Virginia’s School of Continuing and Professional Studies has/requires what it calls [“The Capstone Project”](http://www.scps.virginia.edu/bachelor-of-interdisciplinary-studies/capstone), described as

> “a two-semester process in which students pursue independent research
>   on a question or problem of their choice, engage with the scholarly
>   debates in the relevant disciplines, and - with the guidance of a
>   faculty mentor - produce a substantial paper that reflects a deep
>   understanding of the topic,”

which seems similar to what you are describing.
Again, it’s not a single word, but I have seen/heard it shortened and referred to simply as “my Capstone is/involves ...” when the context is clear.

Comment: It is fairly common for U.S. universities to offer capstone programs, but they commonly culminate in an undergraduate thesis (or finals project, or recital, or other equivalent), while the OP has specifically excluded theses.

Comment: Your UVa link goes to Univ of New Mexico.